# Line and Polygons Intersect Results QGIS 3.0

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, intersect

Dark Green - Line

Light Green - Buffer created from Line

Pink Polygons - Parts of the black polygons that fall within the buffer zone

I have this line going though a bunch of polygons.
The result I need is the overall footage of the Line that potentially intersects the black polygons. The buffer is what defines the potential intersects.

I have come up with a few methods, but they are very complicated with many steps.
I was hoping someone knows a simple or simpler solution to do this.
My current solution goes like this Buffer, Intersect, Dissolve, Multipart to Singlepart, Bounding Boxes, Expand Bounding Boxes, Dissolve, Intersect, Multipart to Singlepart, Add $length attribute.
[image]